# Django filtering over a tsvector column

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My Django application has a backend postgres database with a tsvector column that whose values are already computed and indexed. I want to use Django's ORM to do a full text search over that column with a query that would look something like this:

```
SELECT [fields] FROM [table] WHERE tsvector_column @@ plainto_tsquery('TEXT HERE');
```

The problem I am running into is, when I use `annotate` and `SearchVector`, Django seems to re-`to_tsvector` over the `tsvector` column, resulting in an error.

This is what I am doing:

```
Posts.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('THE_TS_VECTOR_COLUMN'),).filter(search='SEARCH TEXT')
```

How would one do this in Django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
I used `inspectdb` to create the database model, so it guessed that the type was a `TextField`. I changed it to a `SearchVectorField` as follows:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField

class CLASSNAME(models.Model):
    THE_TS_VECTOR_COLUMN = SearchVectorField(null=True)
```

Then I updated the query to this:

```
query = SearchQuery("TEXT TO SEARCH")
CLASSNAME.objects.annotate(rank=SearchVector(F('THE_TS_VECTOR_COLUMN'), query))
```

The resulting query was this:

```
SELECT [ALL FIELD VALUES] FROM "CLASSNAME" WHERE "CLASSNAME"."THE_TS_VECTOR_COLUMN" @@ (plainto_tsquery(TEXT TO SEARCH)) = true
```

And that's exactly what I wanted. Great!